# How to detect an empty result with Go Firebase-Admin SDK when data at the path doesn't exists

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-admin

I'm using the following code to get an object from a Firebase realtime database.

```
type Item struct {
    title string `json:"title"`
}
var item Item
if err := db.NewRef("/items/itemid").Get(ctx, &item); err != nil {
    log.Infof(ctx, "An error occured %v", err.Error())
}
log.Infof(ctx, "Item %v", item)
```

If no data exists at the given path in the realtime database the SDK will not return an error, instead I will end up with an empty struct in the variable `item`.

What would be the cleanest/most readable way to detect that the data at the path is not there?

I've searched for hours but couldn't find a clear cut answer to this question.

Comment: Does *node* refer to `item` instance here?

Comment: Perhaps unmarshal the reference to a map and see if the map comes out empty?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka thanks for the reply. In the current workaround I'm checking the `title` property of `item` to see if it contains a valid string, but there should be an easier way to do this. I'm quite shocked that the official documentation doesn't give any hint, it seems such a common thing to do.

Comment: RTDB returns `null` when queried on a non-existing path. And Go will silently unmarshal `null` to any variable you specify. I think for most applications, unmarshaling to a `map` or an `interface{}` followed by a nil check is good enough to detect non-existence. If you need something more advanced, perhaps look into implementing a custom unmarshaller (I'll add an example shortly).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this problem:

```
type NullableItem struct {
    Item struct {
        Title string `json:"title"`
    }
    IsNull bool
}

func (i *NullableItem) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if string(b) == "null" {
        i.IsNull = true
        return nil
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &i.Item)
}

func TestGetNonExisting(t *testing.T) {
    var i NullableItem
    r := client.NewRef("items/non_existing")
    if err := r.Get(context.Background(), &i); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if !i.IsNull {
        t.Errorf("Get() = %v; want IsNull = true", i)
    }
}
```

As a best practice you should also implement `MarshalJSON()` function.